# BlackBerry Field Alignment

Tags: blackberry, horizontalfieldmanager

I am using HorizontalFieldManager with Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH and Field.FIELD_HCENTER but Field.FIELD_HCENTER is not working below is how I am constructing HorizontalFieldManager

HorizontalFieldManager horizontalContainer = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH | FIELD_HCENTER);

Answer (score 5):

The 
Field class provides the following style bits for alignment:

Horizontal alignment styles

- FIELD_LEFT
- FIELD_HCENTER
- FIELD_RIGHT

Vertical alignment styles

- FIELD_TOP
- FIELD_VCENTER
- FIELD_BOTTOM

The horizontal alignment styles are only recognized when a Field is added to a VerticalFieldManager, and the vertical alignment styles only apply when a Field is added to a HorizontalFieldManager. Fields added to a HorizontalFieldManager are ALWAYS aligned to the left.

Comment: yes buddy I am using FIELD_HCENTER on HorizontalFieldManager  but it's only working when I am using it alone to construct HorizontalFieldManager  like  HorizontalFieldManager horizontalContainer = new HorizontalFieldManager(FIELD_HCENTER); but I need both FIELD_HCENTER and USE_ALL_WIDTH

Comment: FIELD_HCENTER will not have any effect on HorizontalFieldManager , it will only work for VerticalFieldManager

Answer (score 1):

Declare in the following format

HorizontalFieldManager horizontalContainer = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH |DrawStyle.HCENTER);

Answer (score 0):

Try like this in separate class and see the output:

```
HorizontalFieldManager hr=new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
hr.add(new LabelField("Black",Field.FOCUSABLE));        
hr.add(new LabelField("Berry",Field.FOCUSABLE));
add(hr);
```

Enough;